# How to remove '[]' from pandas dataframe output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python function which creates simulated values for different headings. The result I am getting is  `[{"random values"}]`

How do I remove the square brackets so that my output is `{"random values}`

Comment: `return parsed[0]` should do the job.

Comment: if that is the end goal, why you should not create dataframe inbetween, just create the `dict` and use `json.dumps()`